# Use same formatting variable for multiple Excel workbooks

Tags: python, format, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to use same formatting variable for formatting multiple excel workbooks using xlsxwriter? If yes, how? Currently I am able to use formatting variable for single excel workbook as I am initializing it using workbook.add_format method but this variable is bounded to that workbook only.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use same formatting variable for formatting multiple excel workbooks using xlsxwriter?

No.

A formatting object is created by and thus, tied to, a workbook object.

However, there are other ways of doing what you need to do such as storing the properties for the format in a dict and using that to initialize several format objects in the same way.